# How do you calculate $P(A|B)$ if you know only $P(A), P(B|\neg A)$?

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

I've been studying probability to develop a more intuitive sense of calculating probabilities as a medical practitioner.  One example that came up in discussing the importance of *prior probabilities* was HIV testing.  In the example the book **The Laws of Medicine by Siddhartha Mukherjee** gives, he gives the problem of calculating the probability of someone having HIV given that they have a positive ELISA test.  Here's what we know:

The probability of HIV being present in the population: $P(A) = \frac{1}{1000}$

The probability of a false positive (Getting a positive test ($B$) result given that the person doesn't have HIV ($A'$)): $P(B|A') = \frac{1}{1000}$

We want to find the probability that someone has HIV given that they have a positive test result: $P(A|B)$?

My first thought is that we don't have enough information to solve this.  Here's the math to back this up:

$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} = \frac{P(A)P(B|A)}{P(B)}$

From the information we're given, there's no way of finding $P(B|A)$.  So based on the information given in the book, there's no way of calculating $P(A|B)$.  Is this right?  If not, I'd like to find a pathway towards calculating $P(B|A)$ using the information I'm provided.  The big thing here for me is to understand intuitively when some probability isn't computable and if it is computable, is there a simple/intuitive way to do it. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you are supposed to assume that $P(B \mid A) = 1$. Alternatively, assign a different probability, or include that probability as a variable in your answer (that is, you given the probability $P(A \mid B)$ as a function of $P(B \mid A)$).

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32933/describing-bayesian-probability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rough intuition: imagine a population of 1000 people that perfectly reflects the statistics. Then you'll get one positive test from the one infected person (assuming there are negligible false negatives) and one positive test from the 999 people who are HIV free. So the probability of a positive test indicating real illness is 1/2.

I think this method (sometimes called "natural frequencies") offers more insight than Bayes' Theorem on conditional probabilities.

Read http://opinionator.blogs.nytimes.com/2010/04/25/chances-are/ to see how often medical practitioners get this wrong.

Comment: I consider this "rough intuition" to be an intuitive approach to Bayes' Theorem. In this case it is indeed "rough": all the numbers are approximate, including the 1/2. That result is a lot more accurate than what people are likely to guess without applying at least this much rigor to their estimate, however.

Comment: This answer is what the book I have states, but it doesn't make sense to me with the assumptions present.  The number $1 - P(B|A')$ is not the same as $P(B|A)$.  But if I use that number, you can calculate it out to get 50%.  I'm confused how the rough intuition works even though I'm pretty sure you can't calculate it with the information present and Bayes' Theorem.

Comment: Ahh, you used the assumption that false negatives were negligible.  Now your rough intuition makes sense to me.  So unless I assume that or have the actual number, there is no way for me to solve this, right?

Comment: @Rye_yawn Right. The example in the link I point to has a nonzero false negative.

Comment: @DavidK I did some rounding since probabilities were all small, but the method is not an approximation. It's exact and equivalent to Bayes' Theorem if you use the actual probabilities of false +/- and incidence to fill in the two way contingency table. Many people find it easier to understand.

Comment: "Rounding" is a form of approximation. But yes, the method can be done with exact numbers. If an expectation of $0.999$ false positives is intuitive enough, you can just use the exact numbers; or you can try a population of one million and use whole numbers.