# Statistical probability of being sick

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

You have a machine that has a $0.9$ probability to give the correct diagnosis of a flu disease (similar for both the negative and positive diagnoses).
The probability of having the disease is $0.01$ for the general public. You know that a person sampled from the population was diagnosed as positive for the flu by this medical device.
Given this observation, what is the probability of that person having the disease?

I have no idea how to solve this, I think the population follows a normal distribution, but I can't think of anything. I would like you to explain to me what I should do. Thank you!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2919442/what-is-the-probability-that-the-person-actually-has-the-disease

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3910842/a-particular-disease-affects-0-1-of-the-population/3910856#3910856

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

Suppose you had $1000$ people.

- How many would you expect to have the disease?

  - How many of those would you expect to test positive?
- How many would you expect to *not* have the disease?

  - How many of those would you expect to test positive?
- So how many in total would you expect to test positive?

  - What proportion of those testing positive would you expect to have the disease?

Comment: Man I used 1 million and I did: 10000 sick → 90% of 10000 = 9000 (TP), 10000 - 9000 = 1000 (FN), 990000 not sick → 90% of 990000 = 891000 (TN) and 990000 - 891000 = 99000 (FP). Then P = TP/(TP + TN), but if I do that then I get 0,01, the initial probability T-T. What is wrong now?!?!?!?

Comment: @Alex100 $1$ million total; $10,000$ sick, $9,000$ positive and sick, $990,000$ not sick, $99,000$ positive and not sick, $108,000$ positive in total, $\frac{TP}{TP+FP}=\frac{9,000}{108,000}=\frac{1}{12} \approx 8.33\%$ expected proportion of positives who are sick

Comment: Thanks man, I understood and I already turned in the homework