# Find the conditional probability of this event.

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability

Suppose a lab test has the following statistics for detecting a certain disease.

$A$ is the event that the test result is positive, and $B$ is the event the tested person has the disease.

$P(A \mid B) = 0.95$ and $P(A \mid B') = 0.002,$ and $0.5$% of population actually has the disease.

Find the probability that a person has the disease given that the test result is positive.

The probability looks like $P(D \mid A),$ but how do I find the probability of $D$??

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your own thoughts, the effort made so far, and the specific difficulties you faced that got you stuck. Otherwise this question is likely to be closed via community votes. Also, please click on the tiny `edit` and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly typeset math symbols.

Comment: What is $D$ here? Don't you mean $B$?

Comment: I am really confused. What is B? Is B 0.5%?

Comment: Generally you want to measure all probabilities over the same probability space. In this case it's the probability space that exists before the test is administered, so $P(B) = 0.005$ (that is, $0.5$%), as given in the problem statement.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32933/describing-bayesian-probability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$B$ is the event that the tested person has the disease. So, if we assume that this person was just a random person from the population as a whole (in other words, if we know nothing more about this person other than that it is some member of the population at large), then $P(B)$ is the same as the probability of anyone from the population having the disease, i.e. $0.5$%