# What's the probability that person is healthy?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

My question looks like this:

> Using X-ray probability to find out that person is sick: **a=0.98**. Probability to accidentally identify the disease for health person: **b=0.3**. Let's say that there is 10 percent of sick people in the world. What's the probability, that person is healthy even after he was identified a ill person?

My solution:

> P(A)= **0.98*0.3*0.1=0.0294**

But I'm not sure if this is correct.

Any help appreciate, thanks!

Comment: It is not correct.  Work out the probability that  a person is sick and is diagnosed as sick, and the probability that a person is healthy but diagnosed as sick.  Then combine these to find the overall probability of being diagnosed as sick, and thus find the conditional probability

Comment: Then a=0.98 probability has no impact for the answer?

Comment: I would assume $a=0.98$ affects the probability a sick person is diagnosed as sick (though the wording is less than perfect) and so affects the final answer

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32933/describing-bayesian-probability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A person can either be healthy or sick with probabilities 0.9 and 0.1 (say $Pr(H)$ and $Pr(\bar{H})$). It is given that the probability that a healthy person maybe accidentally be misdiagnosed is 0.3, this means that $Pr(Positive|H) = 0.3$. We are asked the probability $Pr(H|Positive)$.

Also given that a person is identified with the disease (irrespective of whether or not he has it) as 0.98. That is,
$$
Pr(Positive) = 0.98
$$
By Bayes' rule,
$$
Pr(H|Positive) = \frac{Pr(Positive|H)\times Pr(H)}{Pr(Positive)}
$$

But we can understand some more properties of the drug by exploring,
$$
Pr(Negative|H) = 1- Pr(Positive|H) = 0.7
$$ 
$$
Pr(Positive) = Pr(Positive|H) + Pr(Positive|\bar{H})
$$
$$
\implies Pr(Positive|\bar{H}) = Pr(Positive) - Pr(Positive|H) = 0.78
$$

This also means,
$$
Pr(Negative|\bar{H}) = 0.22
$$

This drug clearly has an alarming false positive rate. Undertandable as it seems to classify 98% of the population as sick even though only 10% actually are. Like @drhab has pointed out, this is a classic example of Bayes' rule in action.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

- $P\left(\text{healthy}\mid\text{ill tested}\right)P\left(\text{ill tested}\right)=P\left(\text{ill tested}\mid\text{healthy}\right)P\left(\text{healthy}\right)$
- $P\left(\text{ill tested}\right)=P\left(\text{ill tested}\mid\text{healthy}\right)P\left(\text{healthy}\right)+P\left(\text{ill tested}\mid\text{ill}\right)P\left(\text{ill}\right)$

Based on these equalities (do you agree that they are correct?) and your data you can find $P\left(\text{healthy}\mid\text{ill tested}\right)$.

Give it a try (and "discover" the so-called rule of Bayes).