# Probability of a false negative

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

A population includes a fraction m of individuals carrying a disease exists and has the following characteristics:

*P(positive test | individual with the disease) = p*

*P(positive test | individual without the disease) = r*

What is the probability of a false negative : *P(individual with the disease | negative test)* ?

Here is what I have so far:

Let W = with the disease, ~W = without the disease;

Let + = positive test, - = negative test

From the given, we have: *P(W) = m, P(~W) = 1-m*

We want P(W | -) = (P(- |W) P(W))/(P(-)) = (P(- | W)P(W)/(P(- | W)P(W) + P(- ~W)P(~W))

We have: P (+) = P(+|W)P(W) + P(+|~W)P(~W) = p * P(W) + r * P(~W)

However, I do not know how to proceed from here. Could anyone please help me? Thank you very much!

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32933/describing-bayesian-probability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it almost right. You write $P(W|-)=P(-|W)P(W)/P(-)$, and you know everything except $P(-)$: $P(-|W)=1-p$ and $P(W)=m$.

On the other hand, you write the correct expression for $P(+)$, but then you know $P(-)=1-P(+)$. That is, $P(-)=1-pm-r(1-m)$.

---

Here is an alternate solution, where I compute directly $P(-)$ instead of $P(+)$.

The probability that the test is negative is

$$P(-)=P(W)P(-|W)+P(\sim W)P(-|\sim W)=m(1-p)+(1-m)(1-r)$$

The probability that the test is negative and the person has the disease is

$$P(-\cap W)=P(W)P(-|W)=m(1-p)$$

Therefore, the probability that a person has the disease, given that the test is negative, is

$$P(W|-)=\frac{P(-\cap W)}{P(-)}=\frac{m(1-p)}{m(1-p)+(1-m)(1-r)}$$

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed response! Now I understand!