# Probability Question (Bayes' theorem)

Tags: probability-distributions

A pregnant woman lives in an area where the Zika virus is fairly rare: $1$
in $1000$ people have it. Still, she is concerned; so she gets tested. There
is a good but not perfect test for the virus - it gives a positive reading
with probability $0.99$ if the person has the virus and a positive reading
with probability $0.05$ if the person does not. Her reading is positive.
What is the probability that she has the virus?

(a) About $2\%$

(b) About $10\%$

(c) About $ 80\%$

(d) About $20\%$

Comment: Hi Pooja. Would you give us some context to this problem? What have you tried?

Comment: i was thinking of it as a binomial problem but could'nt figure it out..could'nt do much

Comment: When providing clarification that is essential, please click on the tiny `edit` and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) and improve the **body of the post** instead of commenting.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32933/describing-bayesian-probability

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use a *fourfold table*. They're extremly helpful when it comes to dealing with probability. Suppose we are working with $100000$ people. Let 
$Z=$"has Zike", $\overline Z$="doesn't have Zike", $T$="positive test", $\overline T$="negative test". Then

\begin{array}{c|lcr}
 & Z & \overline Z & \sum\\
\hline
T & \color{red}{99} & 4995 & 5094 \\
\overline T & 1 & 94905 & 94906 \\
 \sum& 100 & 99900 & 100000
\end{array}

The pregnant woman's test states that she has Zika. So we want to calculate the probability $P$, that among the $5094$ people who received a positive test, she belongs to the $99$ who indeed have Zika. Thus

> $$P=\frac{99}{5094}\approx 2\%$$

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional probability!

First $1$ in $1000$ is the same as $0.1\%$, then calculate the probability that she has the disease:

$$P(Diseased)=(0.001*0.99)+(0.999*0.05)=0.05094$$

Next we use conditional probability:

$$P(Diseased|Positive)=\frac{0.001*0.999}{0.05094}$$

So this is equal to $0.0196.....$ which is $1.96\%$. Therefore a) is the correct answer!