# Chance of infection when a coronavirus testing kit is faulty

Tags: probability, solution-verification, conditional-probability

This is just a hypothetical question I made up.

> Assume that the coronavirus infects $1$ in $10$ persons. So, $P(D)=0.1,P(D^C)=0.9$. The RAPID testing kits developed to detect the presence of antibodies in the blood are not highly accurate. Their accuracy is $0.3$. Thus, $P(T|D)=0.3=P(T^C|D^C)$.

(i) What is the chance that a person has the disease, given he tests positive? $P(D|T)$

(ii) What is the chance that a person has the disease, given he tests positive twice? $P(D|TT)$

*Solution.*

(i) $P(D|T)=\frac{P(DT)}{P(T)}=\frac{P(T|D)P(D)}{P(T|D)P(D)+P(T|D^C)P(D^C)}=\frac{(0.3)(0.1)}{(0.3)(0.1)+(0.7)(0.9)}=0.04545=4.5 \%$

(ii) $P(D|TT)=\frac{P(DTT)}{P(TT)}=\frac{P(T|TD)P(TD)}{P(TT)}=\frac{P(T|TD)P(T|D)P(D)}{P(TT|D)P(D)+P(TT|D^C)P(D^C)}=\frac{P(T|TD)P(T|D)P(D)}{P(T|TD)P(T|D)P(D)+P(T|TD^C)P(T|D^C)P(D^C)}=0.02$

Are the above probabilities correct? And why does the chance of being infected fall, after two rounds, when in fact, the test should confirm, that you have the disease intuitively?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32933/describing-bayesian-probability

Answer (score 1):

I tried switching the numbers and taking another testing kit with $P(T|D)=0.7$. In this case, the more you test, the more certain you are that you have the disease given additional information.

In the hypothetical posed above, as $P(T|D) < 0.5$, I believe that you become more and more doubtful, if you contracted the disease.