# Probability Homework

Tags: probability

A hospital is testing patients for a certain virus. If a patient has the virus, the test is designed to return "positive" result. If a patient does not have disease, the test should return a "negative" result. The test is not perfect however, and may give incorrect result.

*10% of patients have the virus

*98% of patients who have the virus will test positive

*5% of patients who don't have the virus will incorrectly test positive

A randomly selected patient tests positive for the virus. Determine the probability that the patient has the virus.

P(V)=?

Choices:

-0.143

-0.045

-0.098

-0.685

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32933/describing-bayesian-probability

Answer (score 3):

I don't want to directly give you the answer as you should definitely attempt it if it is homework, but a great place to start would be constructing a tree diagram, an example of which can be found here https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/probability-tree-diagrams.html.

To build the tree diagram, think about what you are looking for. The first set of branches would be whether a patient has the virus. 90% do not and 10% do, so those would be the probabilities for leg of the first branch.

Next, off of each of those will be another branch that says whether or not the patient would test positive for the virus. On the branch that does not have the virus, 5% will test positive and 95% will test negative. For the branch that does have the virus, 98% will test positive and 2% will test negative. You now have 6 different probabilities for different events. Using the tree diagram method in the link, you can solve for the probabilities you are looking for.

Good luck and I hope this helps!