Is "mutual likelihood of something" (defined as $\frac{\Pr(A \cap B)}{\Pr(A)\Pr(B)}$) a thing in Math?
My friend use this variable a lot. He called it mutual likelihood.
$$ML= \frac{\Pr(A \cap B)}{\Pr(A)\Pr(B)} $$
Notice that the number is just
$$\frac{\Pr(A|B)}{\Pr(A)}$$
and
$$\frac{\Pr(B|A)}{\Pr(B)}$$
So it basically tells us how much more likely something is happening if we know another variable is happening.
I used his method to answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3694368/22644 by the way. You can see that it gives simple answer.
It's kind of useful to quickly answer questions like this.
Say a test for a disease has 5% false positive and 0% false negative.
Say someone is tested positive.
What is the chance that he is really sick?
Say the natural chance that someone is sick is 1 out of 1000.
With that formula we can compute
$$ML= \frac{0.001}{0.05 \cdot 0.001} $$
We get around 20.
So knowing one variable means the other variable is 20 times more likely. So the chance that a person is sick is around 2%. If he tested positive, his chance of being sick jump from 0.001 to 0.02. If he is sick, his chance of being tested positive jump from 5% to 100%. In each case the probability jump 20 times and I don't see this being seen more intuitively otherwise.
And that's very intuitive. Notice that if someone is sick he will test positive. If someone is tested positive he may not be sick. That's because the probability of being sick start of so low.
Also it looks like correlation. But I don't quite understand the connection.
I wonder if someone can tell me if there is a Math terms for this.
And then tell me the connection between this formula and correlation.
Any good probability book to learn more?

$0 \le  \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A)P(B)} \le \frac{1}{\max\big(P(A),,P(B)\big)}$ and $\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A)P(B)}=1$ iff $A$ and $B$ are independent.

Not sure if it's true. A and B may have negative correlation where if A happens B is less likely to happen.

@user4951 Negative correlation in that sense corresponds to the $ML < 1$ case: learning that $A$ happens will multiply the probability of $B$ by something less than $1$, decreasing it. We still have $ML \ge 0$, because learning that $A$ happens should never make the probability of $B$ negative!

You can say

$0 \le  \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A)P(B)} \le \frac{1}{\max\big(P(A),\,P(B)\big)}$
$\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A)P(B)}=1$ iff $A$ and $B$ are independent.

Let's write $P(A)$ as $p_A$ and $P(B)$ as $p_B$ (assuming both are strictly between $0$ and $1$) and $P(A \cap B)$ as $p_{A,B}$, and use $\mathbf 1_A$ and $\mathbf 1_B$ as indicator random variables for the events.   Then

the covariance of $\mathbf 1_A$ and $\mathbf 1_B$ is $p_{A,B}-p_Ap_B$

positive when $\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A)P(B)}>1$,
negative when $\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A)P(B)}<1$,
and zero (with independence) when $\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A)P(B)}=1$


the correlation of $\mathbf 1_A$ and $\mathbf 1_B$ is $\frac{p_{A,B}-p_Ap_B}{\sqrt{p_A(1-p_A)p_B(1-p_B)}}$

positive when $\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A)P(B)}>1$,

$+1$ when $p_{A,B}=p_A=p_B$, i.e. when $A=B$ almost surely


negative when $\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A)P(B)}<1$,

$-1$ when $p_A+p_B=1$, i.e. when $A=B^c$ almost surely


and zero when $\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A)P(B)}=1$

$0$ when $p_{A,B}=p_Ap_B$, i.e. when $A$ and $B$ are independent





