# Bayes: disease probability given test and symptoms

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

Let S be symptoms, D disease and T a positive test. We have $P(S) = .2, P(D|S) = .5, P(D) = .01, P(T|D) = .99, P(T) = .1, P(ST|D) = .1$ and $P(T|S) = .5$.

I want to find $P(D|ST)$, so the probability someone has the disease given symptoms and a positive test.

From Bayes I get $P(D|ST) = \frac{P(ST|D)P(D)}{P(ST)}$, I also know $P(ST) = P(S) P(T|S)$.

So I then get (.1 * .01) / (.2 * .5) = .01. So a 1% chance you have the disease given S and T.

Is there a fundamental way to derive the same probability when you for instance don't know $P(ST|D)$ but you have to derive it?

Comment: do you mean $P(S\cap T|D)$ when you write $P(ST|D)?$

Comment: Yes ST stands for "S AND T"

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32933/describing-bayesian-probability

Answer (score 0):

You can derive all these values fundamentally if you have the joint distribution of the random variables S, D, and T. You can then take integrals of the joint PDF (or sums over the joint PMF) to find these values.

Here is a khan academy video that explains the concept in the two variable case.

https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-statistics/analyzing-categorical-ap/distributions-two-way-tables/v/marginal-distribution-and-conditional-distribution