# What's the probability of an accurate diagnosis?

Tags: probability, solution-verification

> Let's assume that 5% of the population has disease D. We have a test that determines if a person has that disease. For people who do have the disease, the test is accurate 95% and 90% for people who do not have the disease. What is the probability of an accurate diagnosis for a randomly selected person?

My attempt:

Events

$D = \{$ random person has the disease $\} \implies \mathbb{P}(D)=5\% = 0.05$

$\overline{D} = \{$ random person doesn't have the disease $\}\implies \mathbb{P}(\overline{D})=1-\mathbb{P}(D) = 0.95$

$T = \{$ test gives a positive result (the disease is present)  $\}$

$\overline{T} = \{$ test gives a negative result (no disease)  $\}$

For people who have the disease, the test is 95% accurate $\implies \mathbb{P}(T|D)=0.95$.

For people who don't have the disease, the test is 90% accurate $\implies \mathbb{P}(\overline{T}|\overline{D})=0.90$.

---

5% of the total population has the disease and out of those 5%, the test will correctly diagnose 95% i.e.

$\mathbb{P}(D)\cdot\mathbb{P}(T|D) = 0.05 \cdot 0.95 = 0.0475$

95% of the total population doesn't have the disease and out of those 95%, the test will correctly diagnose 90% i.e.

$\mathbb{P}(\overline{D})\cdot\mathbb{P}(\overline{T}|\overline{D}) = 0.95 \cdot 0.90 = 0.855$

We conclude that the test will correctly diagnose $0.0475 + 0.855 = 0.9025 = 90.25\%$ of the total population i.e. for a randomly selected person, the probability of a correct diagnosis is $90.25\%$.

Comment: Are you just asking for verification?  If so, then yes.  Your method and calculation are correct.

Comment: Yes! I've been looking at examples for this kind of stuff and it always involves Bayes so I assumed that I oversimplified things. The examples always ask for the probability $\mathbb{P}(D|T)$ but it doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: Your answer is correct. Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2279851/applied-probability-bayes-theorem/2279888#2279888

Comment: Bayes would come into play if you tried to draw a conclusion from a particular test result.  A standard question in this situation would be "suppose a random patient tests positive for the disease.  Find the probability that the patient actually has the disease."

Comment: Thank you both for the verification and additional info! What do I do now? Do I answer my own question, will a moderator close it or do I just leave it as it is? I also added the solution-verification tag.

Comment: You could close it or, if you like, you could post your solution below and accept it.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32933/describing-bayesian-probability