# Alice and Bob sometimes lie; a die is thrown and they claim different results; what is the probability that Bob is being honest?

Tags: probability

> Alice speaks the truth with probability $3/4$ and Bob speaks the truth with probability $2/3$. A die is thrown and both Alice and Bob observe the number. Afterwards, Alice asserts to Carl (who does not know the number) that the number is $3$ while Bob says (to Carl) the number is $1$. Find the probability that the number is actually $1$.

> **UPDATE:** To clear ambiguity, note that if person decides to lie, he/she will choose a false answer randomly from all the possible false answer ($\{1, 2, \cdots, 6\}$ - $\{\text{The number that actually showed up}\}$). Also, a die is thrown, and then both Alice and Bob will see the number. Then, they will lie/say truth accordingly.

**My attempt:**

Case $1$: Number $1$ showed up.

Chance of all this happening = $\frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{2}{3} \cdot \big(\frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{5}\big) = \frac{1}{180}$

Case $2$: Number $3$ showed up

Chance of all this happening = $\frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{3}{4} \cdot \big(\frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{5}\big) = \frac{1}{120}$

Case $3$: Other number showed up

Chance of all this happening = $\frac{4}{6} \cdot (\frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{5}) \cdot (\frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{5}) = \frac{1}{450}$

So, total = $\boxed{\frac{\frac{1}{180}}{\frac{29}{1800}} = \frac{10}{29}}$

Is my attempt correct? If not, how to do this problem?

Comment: If the problem is changed to "after dice was down and appeared the number, Alice and Bob went to watch the dice and say/lie to me, and I deduce the result from what I heard from Alice and Bob", then this will affect the chance. But now Alice and bob are to say something before the dice landing down, so they are just to make "predictions". why this prediction can affect the true probability for a fair dice?

Comment: Problems like this are always a bit ambiguous because the author seldom explains what "lie" means.  This is usually clear for a True/False question but here?  Are we to guess that a liar chooses a false answer uniformly from the possible answers?  Something else?

Comment: @lulu how would that change the answer?

Comment: @insipidintegrator  If, say, you knew that $A$ strongly preferred to say $3$ when they lied, that would make a big difference.  Here, I should say, it seems clear that we are to guess that they choose uniformly between the possible false answers but there are other contexts in which the ambiguity is harder to resolve.

Comment: @MangoPizza  Where does the $\frac {13}{900}$ come from?  If we add the three probabilities you list we get $\frac {29}{1800}$, no?

Comment: @lulu Oops, sorry. It is $\frac{29}{1800}$

Comment: @lulu If person decides to lie, he/she will choose a false answer randomly from all the possible false answer.

Comment: "uniformly at random", sure.  That's what I guessed.  But that should be stated.  And, with the arithmetic now corrected, I agree with your calculation.

Comment: @DavidK Shouldn't the entire sum, including $\frac{1}{180}$, also be in the denominator sum? That will keep it ${29/1800}$

Comment: Amazing how many different answers you are getting! When obviously only one can be right.

Comment: The error was mine, your work is fine.

Comment: @gnasher729 Why is that obvious? When the problem is ambiguous there will be multiple correct answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we didn’t have the observation then the chance that both lie is 1/12, the chance that both say the truth is 6/12, only Bob lies = 3/12, only Alice lies = 2/12. Our observation tells us they are not both saying the truth. The dice is 1 if and only if only Alice lies. Our observation had probability 6/12, only Alice lies had probability 2/12, so the ratio is 2/6 = 1/3. That’s the probability that the number is 1.

This looks suspiciously different to other answers. Let’s try again, and then try to figure out what’s wrong. (The reader might try that now, and finding a different result without finding the error only shows that *some* calculation is wrong, but not which one).

If we throw 1, the probability of this happening is 2/3 x 1/4 x 1/5 = 2/60 (2/3 that Bob says the truth, 1/4 that Alice lies, 1/5 that she picked 3 and not 2, 4, 5 or 6). If we throw 3, the probability is 3/4 x 1/3 x 1/5 = 3/60. If we throw 2, the probability is 1/3 x 1/4 x 1/5 x 1/5 = 1/60 x 1/5, added for 2, 4, 5, 6 gives 0.8/60. So what we observed happens with probability 5.8/60, it happens if 1 is thrown with probability 2/60, so the probability that 1 is thrown is 2/5.8 (and 3/5.8 for the number 3, and 0.8/5.8 that a different number is thrown, each number with probability 0.2/5.8. Or 10/29 for 1, 15/29 for 3, 1/29 for each other number.

So what’s wrong with the first argument? Here’s the mistake: We had a probability of 1/12 for “both lying”, but we can split that into 1/60 for “both lying in the same way” and 4/60 for “both lying in different ways”. And what we saw ruled out “both lie in the same way”, not just “both say the truth”. That creates a tiny difference in the result.

Comment: So my answer of $10/29$ is correct, right?

Comment: I’m 95% confident that it is. Roughly speaking the answer “3” should be more likely to be correct because Alice says the truth more often, and anything else should be less likely because both lying is unlikely. So 10/29 + 15/29 + 4/29 is where you would expect the answer. The other answers 3/14 and 2/9 seem much too low.

Comment: I wrote a computer program, and $10 / 29$ seems to be the correct answer.

Comment: It is also quite close to my first answer 1/3 which contained a very subtle error  that should have made little difference numerically.

Comment: Oh yes. Then, maybe $1 /3$ may also be correct. Although, atleast the other answers such as $10/19$ or $3 / 14$ or $2/9$ can be eliminated. (But $1/3$ doesn't seem to correct, right?)

Comment: No, the 1/3rd was definitely wrong. Seeing the answers 1 and 3 I excluded the case that both say the truth, which is obviously impossible. I missed excluding the case where both lie in the same way. That case is quite unlikely, so my first answer was _close_ but not correct.

Answer (score 5):

Nice problem!  I think OP has the right answer using a correct method and I have nothing to add in terms of the calculation, but perhaps if we set up some careful notation and also be very precise about our independence assumptions, it will become more clear.  For $k=1,2,3,4,5,6$, define the events

- $D_k$ that the die shows $k$;
- $A_k$ that Alice says it is $k$;
- $B_k$ that Bob says it is $k$.

Then the problem asks for $P(D_1\mid A_3\cap B_1)$.  We'll assume the probabilities
$$P(A_l\mid D_k)=\begin{cases}\frac34&\hbox{if $l=k$}\cr \frac14\cdot\frac15&\hbox{if $l\ne k$,}\end{cases}\qquad
  P(B_m\mid D_k)=\begin{cases}\frac23&\hbox{if $m=k$}\cr \frac13\cdot\frac15&\hbox{if $m\ne k$}\end{cases}$$
and also that Alice's and Bob's responses to any roll are independent in the sense that
$$P(A_l\cap B_m\mid D_k)=P(A_l\mid D_k)P(B_m\mid D_k)$$
for all $k,l,m$.

Then we have
$$\eqalign{P(D_1\mid A_3\cap B_1)
  &=\frac{P(D_1\cap A_3\cap B_1)}{P(A_3\cap B_1)}\qquad
    \hbox{(definition of conditional probability)}\cr
  &=\frac{P(D_1\cap A_3\cap B_1)}{\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^6P(D_k\cap A_3\cap B_1)}\qquad\hbox{(total probability rule)}.\cr}$$
Now using the definition of conditional probability and the above assumptions,
$$\eqalign{P(D_k\cap A_3\cap B_1)
  &=P(A_3\cap B_1\mid D_k)P(D_k)\cr
  &=P(A_3\mid D_k)P(B_1\mid D_k)P(D_k)\cr
  &=\begin{cases}
    \frac14\cdot\frac15\cdot\frac23\cdot\frac16&\hbox{if $k=1$}\cr
    \frac34\cdot\frac13\cdot\frac15\cdot\frac16&\hbox{if $k=3$}\cr
    \frac14\cdot\frac15\cdot\frac13\cdot\frac15\cdot\frac16&\hbox{if $k\ne1,3$,}\end{cases}\cr}$$
and substituting back above gives the answer $\frac{10}{29}$.

Comment: This really is the best answer, because it elucidates the many **ASSUMPTIONS** that are required to solve this **terribly underspecified question** the way that the OP has: **(1)** the question states that $P(A)=\frac34,$ but this does not actually imply that $P(A_l\mid D_k)=$ [as specified by David]; **(2)** the above assumption $P(A_l\cap B_m\mid D_k)=P(A_l\mid D_k)P(B_m\mid D_k)$ is actually neither implied by nor implies that $P(A_l\cap B_m)=P(A_l)P(B_m)$ (explanation at the end of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4478726/21813)).

Answer (score 3):

Since no one seems super confident in their answers, I figured I would contribute my own code that checks numerically. A pretty naive Python script that might take a minute or two on weaker hardware, but it works.

```
import random

# pick a random number from the valid range. 
def die():
    return random.randint(1,6)

# keep picking a random number until it isn't the specified one
def rand_except(n):
    t = n
    while t == n:
        t = die()
    return t

def one_third_chance():
    return random.randint(1,3) == 3

def one_fourth_chance():
    return random.randint(1,4) == 4

# assume bob and alice are both right by default, but assign them
# new numbers if they lose a 1/3 roll or 1/4 roll respectively
def run():
    bob = alice = n = die()
    
    if one_third_chance():
        bob = rand_except(n)
        
    if one_fourth_chance():
        alice = rand_except(n)
        
    return (n, bob, alice)

# record 10 million results from our main function
data = [run() for _ in range(10_000_000)]

# we're only considering cases where alice and bob disagree
cases = [r for r in data if r[1] != r[2]]

# the amount of times bob is right
truthful = sum(1 for r in cases if r[0] == r[1])

chance = truthful / len(cases)
error = (chance - (10/29)) / (10/29) 

print("Valid cases:", len(cases))
print("Bob was correct", truthful, "times")
print(f"Chance: {chance*100}%")
print(f"10/29: {10/29 * 100}%")
print(f"Error: {error*100}%")
```

These were my results:

```
Valid cases: 4831063
Bob was correct 1667199 times
Chance: 34.509982585613147%
10/29: 34.48275862068966%
Error: 0.0789494982781197%
```

So out of 4.8 million cases the results were off by under 0.08% of what you predicted, meaning you're almost certainly correct as the problem is too simple to yield a fraction with enough precision to outperform your answer.

Comment: What do you consider a "valid case"?

Comment: @JensSchauder cases where Alice and Bob disagree

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** This is a tricky one! My initial solution made a silly error in calculating one of the ingredients for $P(A_3|\mathbb{1}^c)$. This updated solution agrees with the OP and the simulation study. I also made the problem a tiny bit more general by allowing the probabilities of lying to be arbitrary.

This is a Bayes Rule question, so there are only [two ingredients we need](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3804761/is-the-rare-disease-actually-good-example-for-bayes-theorem/3804932#3804932): the prior odds and the likelihood ratio. The prior odds of rolling a one are $P(\mathbb{1})/[1 - P(\mathbb{1})] = 1/5$. Now we need the likelihood ratio:
$$
\text{LR} = \frac{P(A_3,B_1|\mathbb{1})}{P(A_3, B_1|\mathbb{1}^c)}
$$
Assume that, conditional on the true roll of the die, Alice and Bob make independent reports. This wasn't stated explicitly but it's reasonable in the context. Then the likelihood ratio simplifies to
$$
\text{LR} = \frac{P(A_3|\mathbb{1})P(B_1|\mathbb{1})}{P(A_3|\mathbb{1}^c)P( B_1|\mathbb{1}^c)}
$$
so we can calculate the likelihood ratio *separately* for Bob and Alice. Bob is easier, so we'll start with him. Let $p$ be the probability that Bob tells the truth. Then,
$$
\frac{P(B_1|\mathbb{1})}{P(B_1|\mathbb{1}^c)} = \frac{p}{(1-p) \times 1/5} = 5 \left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)
$$
since Bob tells the truth with probability $p$, lies with probability $1-p$, and chooses uniformly at random from the 5 numbers that were not rolled when he lies.

Now we'll calculate the contribution from Alice's report. Let $q$ be the probability that she tells the truth. Then we have
$$
P(A_3|\mathbb{1}) = P(\text{Alice Lies}\cap A_3|\mathbb{1}) = P(A_3|\mathbb{1}, \text{Alice Lies})P(\text{Alice Lies}|\mathbb{1}) = 1/5 \times(1-q).
$$
The reasoning here is identical to the *denominator* for Bob, but I wanted to spell it out explicitly because the next step is more involved. For *Alice's* denominator, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
P(A_3|\mathbb{1}^c) &= P(A_3|\mathbb{1}^c, \mathbb{3})P(\mathbb{3}|\mathbb{1}^c) + P(A_3|\mathbb{1}^c, \mathbb{3}^c)P(\mathbb{3}^c|\mathbb{1}^c)\\
&= P(\text{Alice Tells the Truth}) \times 1/5 + P(A_3|\mathbb{1}^c, \mathbb{3}^c) \times 4/5\\
&= q \times 1/5 + P(A_3|\mathbb{1}^c, \mathbb{3}^c) \times 4/5
\end{aligned}
$$
so it remains to calculate $P(A_3|\mathbb{1}^c, \mathbb{3}^c)$. We can do this using the law of total probability:
$$
\begin{aligned}
P(A_3|\mathbb{1}^c, \mathbb{3}^c) &= P(\text{Alice Lies}\cap A_3|\mathbb{1}^c, \mathbb{3}^c) \\
&= \sum_{k=2, 4, 5, 6} P(\text{Alice Lies} \cap A_3| \text{True Roll} = k)P(\text{True Roll = k}|\mathbb{1}^c, \mathbb{3}^c)\\
&= \sum_{k=2, 4, 5, 6} (1 - q) P(A_3| \text{True Roll} = k) \times 1/4\\
&= 4 \times (1 - q) \times 1/5 \times 1/4\\
&= (1 - q) \times 1/5.
\end{aligned}
$$
Finally, we can compute the likelihood ratio contribution for Alice! It is given by
$$
\frac{P(A_3|\mathbb{1})}{P(A_3|\mathbb{1}^c)}  = \frac{(1 - q) \times 1/5}{q \times 1/5 + (1 - q) \times 1/5 \times 4/5} = \frac{(1 - q)}{q + (1 - q) \times 4/5}.
$$
Now, combining the likelihood ratio contributions from Bob and Alice, we obtain
$$
\text{LR} = 5\left( \frac{p}{1 - p}\right) \cdot \frac{(1 - q)}{q + (1 - q) \times 4/5}
$$
and the posterior odds are simply the product of the likelihood ratio and the prior odds:
$$
O = \frac{1}{5} \times \text{LR} = \frac{\displaystyle \left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right) }{\displaystyle \left(\frac{q}{1-q}\right) + 4/5}.
$$
What's nice about writing things this way is that it shows that it's the *odds* of Alice and Bob telling the truth, respectively, that matter for the final solution. Using the values given by the OP: $p/(1-p) = 2$ and $q/(1-q) = 3$, so we obtain $O = \frac{2}{3 + 4/5} = 10/19$. Finally we can convert this to a probability: $O/(1 + O) = 10/29$.

Comment: The conditional independence assumption in my original attempt was fine, but I made a silly calculation error in one of the ingredients. My new answer corrects this.